# click on Button based on Text contain in multiple Rows

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to  perform the following scenario: there is a form where data is entered in multiple rows and every record has its own button and I need to click on specific record based on email address.

HTML Source:

```html
<div id="daily-sales-graph">
  <table class="graph" align="center">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 25px;"></th>
        <th style="width: 170px;">
          <h2 align="center" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;ORDER NUMBER</h2>
        </th>
        <th style="width: 60px;">
          <h2 align="center">&nbsp;AMOUNT</h2>
        </th>
        <th style="width: 100px;">
          <h2 align="center" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;ORDER DATE</h2>
        </th>
        <th>
          <h2 align="center" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;LAST CALLED</h2>
        </th>
        <th>
          <h2 align="center" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;SECURITY CODE</h2>
        </th>
        <th>
          <h2 align="center" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;CUSTOMER'S EMAIL ADDRESS</h2>
        </th>
        <th style="width: 74px;"></th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="rowHighlight">
        <td style="font:12px arial,sans-serif;background-color: Maroon; color:white;"></td>
        <td>ORD2014236247112436</td>
        <td>$30.00</td>
        <td>23-Jun-2014</td>
        <td>23-Jun-2014</td>
        <td>5865</td>
        <td>uatmigrationCust@mailinator.com</td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="OPEN" name="ordDetails" class="button" disabled="&quot;disabled&quot;" onclick="OpenWind('/CRMProcessing/New-Order-Detail-NS2?customerid=20311&amp;ordId=41203&amp;AffiliateId=2041')">
        </td>
      </tr>
```

This is what I've tried so far, but it always selects first record only.

```
driver.get("http://domain.com/");
driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("dinero");
driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"submit\"]")).click();

//new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dpApplication"))).selectByVisibleText("CheapCallingCards");
driver.get("http://ccadmin.dinerotesting.com/CRMProcessing/New-Customer-Orders-NS2");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='daily-sales-graph']/table/tbody/td[2]/td[8]/input")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice about that kind of things is to use the CSS Selector with the [nth-child()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) function.

There's my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbd8bzjm/1/) with a basic exemple.

```
You just have to change the value of the nth-child(**i**)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below xapth, it should work (you can parametrize email id) :

```
//td[text()='uatmigrationCust@mailinator.com']/following-sibling::td/input
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to take absolute xpath.As ur requirement,the data is in table.So xpath of each row will differ by tr(eg:tr[1]/td[2]) and denote the changing tr value to a looping variable.Loop it until the last row of the table.

## snippet

```
for(int i=1;i<rows.length;i++)
{
WebElement element="//html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/tr["+i+"]/..../input"
element.click;
}
```

by this snippet u can traversal through last row of table.
Hope after this u could proceed..